# Cath picker selected item = null Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I want if user won't selection item in `picker` `label`'s text become this: Error! Not full condition!

I tried something like

```
        try
        {
            picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex] = null;
        }

        catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
        {
            Error.IsVisible = true;
            Error.Text = AppResources.ERROR1;
        }
```

But it doesn't works! Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if SelectedIndex is -1 then no item is selected

```
if (picker.SelectedIndex < 0) 
{
  Error.IsVisible = true;
  Error.Text = AppResources.ERROR1;
}
```